# What is the correct romanization of イー?

Tags: loanwords, rōmaji, long-vowels

According to the rules of Hepburn (http://www.halcat.com/roomazi/doc/hep3.html), しいたけ is correctly romanized as *shiitake*. What is the correct romanization of イー as in シート? Should it be *shiito* or *shīto* or *shi-to*?

Comment: By "correct", do you mean "according to the rules described by the particular version of Hepburn linked to in this question"?

Comment: @snailplane The page I linked to does not say anything about イー, I don't think.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: 1) You link to the rules. 2) The rules do not define this case. Hence, there is no solution to the question. What am I missing?

Comment: @Dono - yes, there is no solution **on that page**. I want to find if there is a solution other than **on that page**.

Comment: You could try to get a copy of the book you link to, or, if you consider the now-standard Modified (or Revised) Hepburn to be "correct", get a hold of a copy of the [Kenkyūsha's New Japanese-English Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenkyūsha%27s_New_Japanese-English_Dictionary) (3rd edition or later), which seems to be the official reference.

Comment: @user1205935 I don't think you can reasonably call it "official", but I do own the fifth edition, so I decided to take a look.  This is all it said: **長音**　母音の上に長音符（¯）をつけて示す.  **ā** （アー）, **ū** （ウー）, **ō** （オー）など.  ただし,　本辞典では以下の３都市名に限り、例外として長音符をつけなかった.  **Tokyo** 東京, **Kyoto** 京都, **Osaka** 大阪

Comment: @snailplane Thanks for checking. The 3rd edition seems to be the origin of Revised Hepburn and may as well be the official reference, I would say. I could not find any other official references. There is [ALA-AC](http://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/roman.html) for [Japanese](http://www.loc.gov/catdir/cpso/romanization/japanese.pdf) (PDF), which is kind of official, but doesn't claim to be using strictly Revised Hepburn.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it depends what romanization system you use, but generally (e.g. [Hepburn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization)) one romanizes double /i/ as *ii*, e.g. [しいたけ → *shiitake*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepburn_romanization#I_.2B_I).

However, a vowel lengthened with the 長音 「ー」 (usually in loanwords) is romanized differently:

- **Hepburn**
  a macron over the vowel before it, e.g. シート → *shīto*
  (See *Kenkyūsha's New Japanese-English Dictionary* for modified Hepburn)
- **Kunrei-shiki**
  a circumflex over the vowel before it, e.g. シート → *sîto*
- **Wāpuro rōmaji** (or *wa-puro ro-maji*)
  a hyphen after the vowel, just as is typed, e.g. シート → *si-to*
  <sub>*N.B.* In other systems the hyphen may be inserted for readability.</sub>

Comment: The "loanword" section of the Wikipedia article you point me to is completely unreferenced, so it could just be a speculation on the part of whoever wrote it.

Comment: Do you agree that in Hepburn ローマ字 is romanized as rōmaji?

Comment: yes, like ろうそく is romanized as rōsoku, but this is a different case, because しいたけ is romanized as shiitake.

Comment: Re: "(I stick to Wāpuro rōmaji) use si for し"; in my experience input of either "si" or "shi" will produce し. (I prefer "shi" because that is how it sounds in English.)

Comment: Japanese sh is halfway really between s and English sh. Shi doesn't feel closer than s to me.